# Extracting last modified date, author of files in git repository using python

Tags: python, git, gitpython

Ok so I've been working on extracting data from a remote git repository and generating a csv report listing files based on their last modified date using Python script. I have been able to get the latest code using subprocess and I'm able to generate a report as well. The code snippet for the two functions is as follows:

```
> import subprocess 
> process = subprocess.Popen("git pull",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
> output = process.communicate()[0]
```

for csv generation

```
> with open('excelout1.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
>     wr = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
>     for row in myfilelist:
>         wr.writerow(row)
```

So now, I am getting the last modified date for all files, but the thing is, the date generated is when the files in my local repo were updated, i.e when I take the latest pull,obviously. What I want is the last modified date and author for each file in the REMOTE repository.

The command for generating last modified dates using Git bash is `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} -- git log -1 --format="%ai {}" {} | sort`. I want to know how I could use this command in a python script. I'm fairly new to python and any kind of help is appreciated.

**EDIT**: Current code being used after Mufeed's suggestion

```
import os, csv, glob, time
import pandas as pd
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("git pull", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
p = subprocess.check_output(['git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} -- git log -1 --format="%ai {}" {} | sort'],cwd = "C:\Users\sherin.sunny\git\ng-ui",shell=True) 
print(p)

print ('-'*60)  # just vanity
date_file_list = []
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(".\src\\"):
    # select the type of file, for instance *.jpg or all files *.*
    for file in glob.glob(dirpath + '/*.component.ts'):

        stats = os.stat(file)

        lastmod_date = time.localtime(stats[8])

        date_file_tuple = lastmod_date, file
        date_file_list.append(date_file_tuple)

#print date_file_list  # test
date_file_list.sort()
date_file_list.reverse()  # newest mod date now first
print ("%-40s %s" % ("filename:", "last modified:"))
myfilelist = []
for file in date_file_list:
    # extract just the filename
    folder, file_name = os.path.split(file[1])
    # convert date tuple to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS format
    file_date = time.strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S", file[0])
    myfilelist.append([file_name, file_date])
with open('excelout1.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    wr = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in myfilelist:
        wr.writerow(row)
```

Comment: See [salty crane](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/04/how-use-bash-shell-python-subprocess-instead-binsh/)

Comment: why don't you use the subprocess module itself? subprocess.check_output(['git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} -- git log -1 --format="%ai {}" {}'],shell=True)

Comment: @mufeed that won't use git bash by default

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly. But to get the result he wants, the code I mentioned is enough right? I got the right output after executing that code. Please let me know if I understood this wrong.

Comment: @Mufeed what operating system are you using? If Linux then maybe yes as the default shell would also have access to `xargs`. On windows you'd have to give the path to the git bash executable.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @Peter. I got the point now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your problem correctly. Check the code snippet below. Same Subprocess module gives the output as problem description.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.check_output(['git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} -- git 
log -1 --format="%ai {}" {} | sort'],cwd = "path\to\directory",shell=True) 
#cwd = change working directory   
print(p)
```

**output**

```
b'2018-06-23 09:42:40 -0700 CONTRIBUTING.md\n
2018-06-23 09:42:40 -0700 data_reader.py\n
2018-06-23 09:42:40 -0700 LICENSE\n
2018-06-23 09:43:37 -0700 README.md\n'
```

subprocess.check_output is used to store the output to a variable so that you can extract your required values from it.

Comment: I'm getting the following error

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cd C:/Users/sherin.sunny/git/ng-ui/;git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n1 I{}-- git log -1 --format="%ai {}" {} | sort']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Am I giving the directory name correctly?

Comment: I guess you need to use backward slash while specifying the path as you are using windows system. My code was executed in linux. try cd C:\Users\sherin.sunny\git\ng-ui

Comment: I used your updated code with forward as well as backward slashes. Getting errors in both
For forward:

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} -- git log -1 --format="%ai {}" {} | sort']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: for backward slash:
File "check_fileage.py", line 12
    p = subprocess.check_output(['git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} -- git log -1 --format="%ai {}" {} | sort'],cwd = "C:\Users\sherin.sunny\git\ng-ui",shell=True)
                                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: can you check with double back slashes? for ex: C:\\Users\\sherin.sunny\\git\\ng-ui

Comment: getting the same result as with the forward slash now. I edited the question and posted the entire code. Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: check the above link. It may be useful. I am not able to debug the code as I don't have a windows system with me.

Comment: Ok, I'll dig a little deeper. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think \s and \n in your path is interpreted as space and new line by python. May be that is the error. can you try cwd=r'C:\Users\sherin.sunny\git\ng-ui'

Comment: result's the same. "returned non-zero exit status 1"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173876/discussion-between-mufeed-and-sherin-sunny).